# Read first X bytes of binary file into new files

Tags: c#, filestream, binaryfiles

I am trying to get the first few K of a file and store it into a temporary file without any changes other than length. For some reason, this code seems to be returning something from the middle of the file rather than the beginning.

```
    public static FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"isam.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    public static FileStream shortFile = null;
    int limit = 10000;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        byte[] block = new byte[limit];
        while (stream.Read(block, 0, limit) > 0)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create("tempfile.dat"))
            {
                fs.Write(block, 0, block.Length);
                if (stream.Position > limit)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (stream.Position > limit)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `while` loop should go inside the `using` block, not the other way around. If you only want the first `limit` bytes to be written, you shoudn't use the while loop at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create("tempfile.dat"))
```

It forces creation of a new file for each block read. You need to move above where your first start reading from the stream.

Additionally, the `if(stream.Position > limit)` condition will still be `true` after the first read, since the position should be *exactly at* the `limit` value.

You probably want something more like this:

```
public static FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"isam.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
public static FileStream shortFile = null;
const int limit = 10000;

public MainWindow()
{
    byte[] block = new byte[limit];
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create("tempfile.dat"))
    {
        while (stream.Read(block, 0, limit) > 0 && stream.Position <= limit)
        {
            fs.Write(block, 0, block.Length);
        }
    }
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

or even this:

```
public static FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"isam.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
public static FileStream shortFile = null;
const int limit = 10000;

public MainWindow()
{
    byte[] block = new byte[limit];
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create("tempfile.dat"))
    {
        int bytes = stream.Read(block, 0, limit);
        if (bytes > 0)
        {
            fs.Write(block, 0, bytes);
        }
    }
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was reusing some code where I was looping over each block, but the files were too large so I wanted to shorten them. I forgot to take out the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

File.Create(filename) is overwriting the file each time the loop iterates. You need to append instead, or keep "tempfile.dat" open until your loop is complete.

Comment: Just to expand on this a bit... your `using(...)` statement is going to close the file after code leaves the block, which will overwrite the file every loop iteration unless you do what is suggested and open as append or remove the `using(...)` block and manually open/close the file when you need it done.